# Swift image upload and c# web service

Tags: c#, swift, web-services, upload, multipartform-data

I've been trying to solve this puzzle for days now. My noob skills in swift and c# has caught up with me.

I'm trying to upload an image in swift to a webservice made in c# ..

But no matter what I do I end up getting the same error.

```
Optional(System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary-C59AEB2F-ABB1-4771-8564-D3659108DF7E.

   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()

   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

)
```

here is my Swift function

```
func uploadImages(){

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.xxx.xxx/WebService.asmx/UploadVideoFile?VideoFileData=")

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let image_data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "plainDogFIlledWhite.png")!)

        if(image_data == nil)
        {
            return
        }

        let body = NSMutableData()
        let fname = "test.png"
        let mimetype = "image/png"

        body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"test\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("hi\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(fname)\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append(image_data!)
        body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

        request.httpBody = body as Data

        let session = URLSession.shared


        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            (
            data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data, let response = response, error == nil else {
                print("error")
                return
            }

            let dataString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print(dataString)

        }
        task.resume()
}
```

and I've tried to keep my service as simple as possible ..

c# service

```
[WebMethod]
    public string UploadVideoFile(byte[] VideoFileData)
    {
      return "return this";
    }
```

Comment: `WebMethod` publishes the method as part of an XML-based web service, which only accepts requests wrapped in a SOAP envelope. It cannot accept `multipart/form-data`. If you can modify your server side C# code, you should better write a RESTful APIs, rather than SOAP based services.

Comment: hi .. thx for your advice.
My knowledge towards REST is at a minimum and I therefor have some difficulties setting up the webserver/webconfig's on the webserver (unoeuro.com) so I can make it work .. 
Are there no way that I can make it work as originally intended ??

Comment: You may search for a SOAP library for Swift, but I do not know any and am not sure if you can find a reliable one. If you can add a new web application on your server side, ASP.NET Web API is one the easiest to use framework to build up RESTful APIs. Anyway, you may need to completely rewrite your Swift code (though it's hard to find a good article about SOAP in Swift), or else you may need to completely rewrite your server side app (you can find many, many articles about Web API). It's your choice.